# Offline Android Installation

Tags: android, windows

I have these three files:

> - android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip (81.5 MB)
> - installer_r16-windows.exe (28.1 MB)
> - platform-tools_r10-windows.zip (9.54 MB)

And the system which I will install this SDK has Windows7 and a poor Internet connection.

Are these three files enough to develop Android projects?
How can I install it offline with these files?

Comment: Are you interested in linux installation or windows? Because you have archives for both?

Comment: Umm, In fact I have no idea about these files. It's first time I'm installing Android SDK. Do you mean I do not need `android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip` ?

Comment: Which operating system are you going to install on? What is the size of `android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the ADT bundle from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html it looks like the files you have are considerably out of date.

Comment: After downloading it once, Will I need connect to Internet while installing SDK?

Comment: Only to install extra add-ons. Everything you need to perform basic development is included.

Comment: You should however make a point of getting the Windows USB driver for testing on real devices. It's quite small.